# How to avoid writing a tautological test

Tags: ruby, testing

I'm trying to write a unit test to check that a Ruby model I've defined has an attribute `name`. Using rspec, I have:

```
class MusicianTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  describe Musician do
    let(:musician) { Musician.new }

    describe "attributes" do
      it "has a name" do
        musician.name = "Axel"
        expect(musician.name).to eq("Axel")
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Is this a tautology? Is there a better approach I could use?

Comment: Can you just do `expect(it "has a name")`?

Comment: @AaronBrager That would be nice, but won't work because `it` isn't defined for that context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a few ways you can test it better i think. If your model is an `ActiveRecord` then you can check the `column_names` property

```
musician.column_names.should include 'name'
```

If it's a plain ruby object then you could check if it responds to the setters and getters

```
musician.should respond_to(:name)
musician.should respond_to(:name=)
```

Generally, the rule is that your test should say something about what you're actually testing. Like for example your test looks like you're testing setters and getters, which is totally fine and legit if you do some magic in your setters/getters and want to make sure that things work correctly.

So, in your case, if you're trying to verify that an attribute exists, you should say just that `attributes.include 'name'` or something like that.

On a foot note. If you're doing some vanilla ActiveRecord testing, personally me I wouldn't test the attributes existence, I'd define a `FactoryGirl` factory with attributes that supposed to exist and if for some reason they're missing your tests will crash whenever you spawn a new object with FactoryGirl.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a tautology. You are assigning a value using the setter method `name=`, and reading it using the getter method `name`. If the test succeeds, it means that a setting-getting round trip was idempotent, but that is not tautology. It is meaningful.

As for a proof that it is not tautology, it is possible to define the pair of methods `name=` and `name` in a certain way so that the test fails.